# Autoencoder with Multiple Outputs

Tags: neural-network, autoencoder, generative-adversarial-network, multipleoutputs

How do I make an autoencoder with 2 different images at the output layer? I am asked to average 2 images as input to a neural network and receive both images separately as output.

Comment: Use one common encoder to get the latent code and use two different decoders taking the latent code as input and generating images.

Comment: Do you have a sample code for this or a pseudocode? Also how will I ensure that both the decoders return both images instead of getting the same image twice?

Comment: This is just an initial idea. Apart from your questions, which decoder would output which image and how the other one know about it? is also a question roaming in my mind